# What is the best source of open data on sea level rise in Bangladesh and India?

Tags: data-request, weather, geospatial

I am trying to determine the level of rise in sea levels in coastal areas of India and Bangladesh. I was wondering if anyone knew the best sources of open data--mean local sea level, mean local tide level--for this type of information.

From what I gather, it seems like mean sea level or tidal data is the best way to go. That is just because sea level is not a constant value, but fluctuates over time. So we need some sort of average tide level--basically how far above sea level the tide extends. Then I can determine which areas of these countries are submerged given this level of tide using existing elevation data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NOAA National Oceangraphic Data Center (NODC) maintains data (and datasets) for sea levels and tides. You can get current (hourly) or historic data back to 1994. The data is collected from 289 stations around the world.

http://www.nodc.noaa.gov/General/sealevel.html

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the info. There are so many sources out there, and this source seems pretty comprehensive.