# What are open data sources about current sea state?

Tags: data-request, data.gov, weather, oceanographic

I wonder where (links/APIs) can be obtained data that is related to current (alike realtime - no past) sea state data (**worldwide**, but regional is good two, salt\waves length\hight etc)?

I am only interested in dynamically changing data as close to realtime as possible. (alike realtime)

Here is what I already found:

- [oceanweather](http://www.oceanweather.com/data/)
- [ndbc.noaa.gov](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/)
- [tidesandcurrents](http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/sltrends/index.shtml)

Comment: Could you please give more details about what sea state information you want? Traffic congestion? Weather? Pollution? Tide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered a question similar to this that has a useful resource for current sea level information:

[What is the best source of open data on sea level rise in Bangladesh and India?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3255/best-source-of-open-data-on-sea-level-rise-in-bangladesh-and-india)

> >
>   The NOAA National Oceangraphic Data Center (NODC) maintains data (and datasets) for sea levels and tides. You can get current (hourly) or historic data back to 1994. The data is collected from 289 stations around the world.
>
> >
>   http://www.nodc.noaa.gov/General/sealevel.html

Comment: I already found ndbc.noaa.gov (see Question)

Comment: @DuckQueen - you listed the National Buoy Data Center (NBDC) vs the National Oceanographic Data Center (NODC). Not sure how much difference there is between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Just posted an answer here: [Extensive Weather or Sea State API?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7361/extensive-weather-or-sea-state-api/12955#12955)

Late answer but in case anyone else finds this post.

We released our API called Storm Glass a couple of months back and it provides up to 22 attributes, including:

- Swell Height
- Swell Direction
- Swell Period
- Coastal Sea Level
- Wave Height
- Wave Direction
- Wave Period
- Water Temperature

See https://stormglass.io for full list of attributes and examples on how to use the API. We do offer a Free developer plan.

*Note: I'm one of the developers building stormglass.io*